# Two column CSV data sort - one column str(ascending) the other column date(descending)

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, sorting

I am interested in knowing how to perform a two-column sort of a CSV file where one column is ascending while the other is descending and need to be parse into an understandable date format.

```
import operator
import csv
import dateutil.parser as dparser

reader = csv.reader(open("2002_NASDAQ.csv"), delimiter=",")

sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=lambda k: (k[0], dparser.parse(k[1])), reverse=True)

with open('2002_NASDAQ_out.csv', 'wb') as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows(sortedlist)
```

If I remove the parse the script runs without errors. However, without the date in the proper format the result are not as desired (ticker-ascending, date-decending).

```
''' Sample sample.csv data
AAME,01-Jan-2002,2.204,2.204,2.204,2.204,0
AAON,01-Jan-2002,7.254,7.254,7.254,7.254,0
AAPL,01-Jan-2002,10.95,10.95,10.95,10.95,0
AAME,02-Jan-2002,5.71,5.71,5.71,5.71,0
AAON,02-Jan-2002,11.125,11.125,11.125,11.125,0
AAPL,02-Jan-2002,13.85,13.85,13.85,13.85,0
AAME,03-Jan-2002,28.82,28.82,28.82,28.82,0
AAON,03-Jan-2002,15.82,15.82,15.82,15.82,0
AAPL,03-Jan-2002,1.725,1.725,1.725,1.725,0
AAME,04-Jan-2002,5.3333,5.3333,5.3333,5.3333,0

''' Example sorted.csv data
AAME,04-Jan-2002,5.3333,5.3333,5.3333,5.3333,0
AAME,03-Jan-2002,28.82,28.82,28.82,28.82,0
AAME,02-Jan-2002,5.71,5.71,5.71,5.71,0
AAME,01-Jan-2002,2.204,2.204,2.204,2.204,0
AAON,03-Jan-2002,15.82,15.82,15.82,15.82,0
AAON,02-Jan-2002,11.125,11.125,11.125,11.125,0
 .
 .
 .
AAPL,03-Jan-2002,1.725,1.725,1.725,1.725,0
'''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional approach is to rely on the fact that Python's sort is stable and to sort twice (note the second key is done first):

```
a = sorted(something, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
a.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
```

**example**

```
>>> a = [ (1, 2), (0, 1), (2, 1), (2, 7) ]
>>> a.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
>>> a.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
>>> a
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 7), (2, 1)]
```

**untested**

```
sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=lambda L: dparser.parse(L[1]), reverse=True)
sortedlist.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
```

Comment: Jon, thanks for your reply.  I understand the logic. When I implemented it, I receive an Unknown String error from the dpaser.parse line.

Comment: Here are the errors thrown back: 
    sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=lambda L: dparser.parse(L[1]), reverse=True)

  File "C:\pysci17\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.py", line 697, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\pysci17\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.py", line 303, in parse
    raise ValueError, "unknown string format"
ValueError: unknown string format

Comment: I could not get the two sorts within the same script to operate properly. However, after I placed them in separate scripts the logic worked perfectly as expected. One the occasion above I referenced the wrong element. After correcting that issue the program ran without error but then created an outfile file with 0 bytes.